# Can I use "default" variable in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm proceeding Spring project on IntelliJ.

I was doing json parsing using gson, but I was having trouble creating a class for parsing.

Among the youtube api, json key values ​​related to searchlist have a problem called **"default"** variable.

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Thumbnails {
    *// Map<String, String> default;*
    Map<String, String> medium;
    Map<String, String> high;

}
```

The current class is the same as above, except for the "default" variable.

I wonder if it is possible to use "default" as a variable value, or whether it is possible to parse json key values ​​into other variable values ​​when executing the `gson.fromJson ()` method.

P.S Attach JSON Response.

```
 "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video-id/default.jpg",
         "width": 120,
         "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video-id/mqdefault.jpg",
         "width": 320,
         "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/video-id/hqdefault.jpg",
         "width": 480,
         "height": 360
     }
 },
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#json-field-naming-support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `default` as a variable name as it's a [*Language Keyword*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) , but you can do this:

```
@SerializedName("default")
Map<String, String> defaultThumbnail; // Or any other name that is not 'default'
```